# Keep track of counter and increment value by one in Django Template

Tags: python, django

Is there way to keep track of a counter in a Django template and increment its value by one only if it meets a certain condition?

For example I want to do something like this:

```
{% with car_counter=0 %}
    {% for car in cars %}
        {% if car.make=="Ford" and car_counter < 3 %}
            {{car.price}}
            ??? increment car_counter ???
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

I would like to only execute the loop 3 times if it meets this condition. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

The Django template language discourages logic in the template. For the example you gave, it would be better to create a queryset with three Ford cars in the view.

```
cars = Car.objects.all()
fords = cars.filter(make="Ford")[:3]
```

Then loop through it in the template:

```
{% for ford in fords %}
    {{ ford.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I understand, but is there a way to do this in the template? I need to do this for the time being, and will go back and update it.

Comment: You could create a template tag (perhaps an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)) and do the filtering there. It isn't possible to increment values in the template as you are trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

There is an inbuilt `add` filter for that . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#add

```
{% with car_counter=0 %}
    {% for car in cars %}
        {% if car.make=="Ford" and car_counter < 3 %}
            {{car.price}}
            {{ car_counter|add:"1" }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

**EDITED**

If you read the documentation, this is what it reads.

> ### Built-in filter reference
>
> `add`
>
> Adds the argument to the value.
>
> For example:
>
> {{ value|add:"2" }} If value is 4, then the output will be 6.

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot increment variables in the template like this.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can: {% car_counter|add:"1" %} results in an "invalid block" error.

Comment: @JohnSmith my bad, {{ car_counter|add:"1" }}  this is the syntax, i missed it

Comment: Your updated version is still incorrect. It will add the strings `0` and `1` to display `1`, but it will not change the value of the variable.

Comment: @Alasdair Please check with the documentation link I shared, it says, Example: {{ value|add:"2" }} If value is 4, then the output will be 6.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken that it would treat `"1"` as a string. However, my main point is that `add` will only affect the value that is displayed. **It does not change the variable in the template for the next loop**.